# Why does the large title not work when I use the Turkish character "ç"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, swift5

Why does the banner not work when I use the Turkish "ç" character?

I've tried everything, everything seems fine. But I only get such an error in the "ç" character, has anyone experienced it before?
How will I solve this situation? I do not have such a problem when I use the Turkish "ü" character.

> **Edit:**
>
> I found the source of the problem guys. I removed the Bottom
> constraint constant value from the view in the scrollview. I just gave
> trailing, leading, top, centerX and centerY.

[image]

Comment: Without having some mini reproducible code, there isn’t much we can do.

Comment: I only processed in storyboard. Can you set up a structure like you see on the gif using navigationcontroller, try it and share the results here?

Comment: No, that would be really time consuming. That’s your job to create and share. If you don’t, people just won’t bother engaging with your question.

Comment: I only processed in the storyboard, how can I explain the code to you?

Comment: Post the the Storyboard XML context in the question, along with everything else you need to recreate your demo. Of course, remove all the unrelated factors to make a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character "Ç" does not seem to be the problem. There must be something else.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for setting up a correct structure and showing me that the problem is not "ç" character.

Comment: Few tips for recording gifs like this: when recording with QuickTime, you can capture a specific window. Even better, in the simulator press `command + R` to record the screen, and then after you have recorded you can right-click on the little video in the corner and save it directly as a GIF. Just a time-saving tip if you didn't already know :)

Comment: You are truly king. Thank you for this tip, I hadn't come across it anywhere until now :)